# Copy slide containing notes from one PowerPoint presentaition to another with OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, office365, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to copy slides from one PowerPoint presentation to another. I have used the procedure outlined in the following article, and it generally works fine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/ee361883(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

However, when the slide to be copied contains notes, the resulting presentation after copying is corrupted. I've noticed that the code generates a new `notesMaster` which is not added to the `notesMasterIdLst` in presentation.xml, and have a suspicion this might be the issue. However, I cannot add the new notes master to the presentation, as a presentation can only have one `notesMaster`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk), Open XML SDK is defined this way:

> The Open XML SDK 2.5 simplifies the task of manipulating Open XML
> packages and the underlying Open XML schema elements within a package.
> The Open XML SDK 2.5 encapsulates many common tasks that developers
> perform on Open XML packages, so that you can perform complex
> operations with just a few lines of code.

It looks like it is not easy to solve your problem using the Open XML SDK. If you use [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://products.aspose.com/slides/net/) you will copy a slide with its notes as shown below:

```cs
var sourceFileName = "example1.pptx";
var targetFileName = "example2.pptx";
var slideIndex = 0;

using (var sourcePresentation = new Presentation(sourceFileName))
using (var targetPresentation = new Presentation(targetFileName))
{
    var slide = sourcePresentation.Slides[slideIndex];
    targetPresentation.Slides.AddClone(slide);
    targetPresentation.Save(targetFileName, SaveFormat.Pptx);
}
```

You can also evaluate [Aspose.Slides Cloud](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/net/) for presentation manipulating. This REST-based API allows you to make 150 free API calls per month for API learning and presentation processing. The following code example shows you how to do the same using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```cs
var slidesApi = new SlidesApi("my_client_id", "my_client_key");

var sourceFileName = "example1.pptx";
var targetFileName = "example2.pptx";
var slideIndex = 1;

using (var sourceStream = File.OpenRead(sourceFileName))
    slidesApi.UploadFile(sourceFileName, sourceStream);

using (var targetStream = File.OpenRead(targetFileName))
    slidesApi.UploadFile(targetFileName, targetStream);

slidesApi.CopySlide(targetFileName, slideIndex, null, sourceFileName);

using (var resultStream = slidesApi.DownloadFile(targetFileName))
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(targetFileName))
    resultStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.

Comment: Note this is a paid product. I'd consider it bad form to leave that out of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the note. We will take this into account in the future.

Comment: @raarts, PowerPoint is also a paid product. You can use Aspose Slides Cloud API to perform 150 operations (calls) for free. I think it is OK to know about such decisions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I managed to solve this issue by doing the following steps:

1. Make the source presentations editable when opening them:

   ```
    using (PresentationDocument mySourceDeck =
    PresentationDocument.Open(
      presentationFolder + sourcePresentation, true))
    {
    PresentationPart sourcePresPart =
      mySourceDeck.PresentationPart;
   ```
2. Copy the notes slide CommonSlideData from the slide, then delete the notes slide part from the slide:

   ```
    sp = (SlidePart)sourcePresPart.GetPartById(slideId.RelationshipId);
    CommonSlideData notesSlideData = null;
    if (sp.NotesSlidePart != null)
    {
      notesSlideData = (CommonSlideData)sp.NotesSlidePart.NotesSlide.CommonSlideData.CloneNode(true);
      sp.DeletePart(sp.NotesSlidePart);
    }
   ```
3. Readd any existing notes slide data by adding a new NotesSlidePart to the copied slide (now added to the target presentation and called destSp), adding relationship parts and a new NotesSlide object initialised with the copied notes slide data.

   ```
    if (notesSlideData != null)
    {
      NotesSlidePart notesSlidePart1 = destSp.AddNewPart<NotesSlidePart>();
      notesSlidePart1.AddPart(destSp);
      notesSlidePart1.AddPart(destPresPart.NotesMasterPart);

      NotesSlide notesSlide = new NotesSlide(notesSlideData);
      notesSlidePart1.NotesSlide = notesSlide;
    }
   ```

**Warning:** The notes slides will be deleted from the source presentation files, so you might want to make a copy of them first, or add them back to the presentation after it has been copied/merged.

This seems to retain at least some existing formatting of the notes slides, such as bold text. However, I have not yet tested this on a lot of different presentations so I suppose there could be some issues if the notes slides are based on very different notes slide masters, but I'm not sure.

Related to this, I ran into a similar issue after getting the notes slides to work, which seemed to be because of any custom xml parts that existed on the presentation to be copied. These presentations worked after adding some code to add relationships to the copied presentation's CustomXmlPart to the target presentation:

```
foreach (var customXmlPart in destSp.GetPartsOfType<CustomXmlPart>())
{
  destPresPart.AddPart(customXmlPart);
}
```